# Create a list through commands

Tags: lists, robust-commands

Is there a way I could do something like

```
\createlist{listone} % A description list specifically
\additem{listone}{item1}{description1}
\additem{listone}{item2}{description2}
 .
 .
 .
\makelist{listone}
```

I really don't know how I would google this to begin with (tried and failed). If you can point me to any documentation or tell me if it is at all possible to create a function like this then that would be amazing! Thank you!

Also if you can point me to the correct tags for this question that would be very appreciated.

---

Edit:

The idea is that you can have various "lists" to which you can add as many items as you need throughout the `.tex`. You then decide to output that description list when you use the command `\makelist`

Comment: What should `\makelist` do?

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear! It is supposed to output the description list that contains the items `item1` and `item2` with their descriptions, which are stored in list `listone`. Basically, it let's you create varios "lists" to which you can add items as you wish and you decide where in the text the list is written by using the command `\makelist`

Comment: try `https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=itemi*+list` or tighter as `https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=itemi*+list+enumerate`

Comment: The indentation is easy.  The hard part is nesting them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with `xparse` and `expl3`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\createlist}{m}
 {
  \seq_new:c { g_mo_list_#1_seq }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\additem}{mmm}
 {
  \seq_gput_right:cn { g_mo_list_#1_seq } { {#2}{#3} }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\makelist}{m}
 {
  \begin{description}
  \seq_map_function:cN { g_mo_list_#1_seq } \__mo_list_item:n
  \end{description}
 }
\cs_new:Nn \__mo_list_item:n { \__mo_list_item:nn #1 }
\cs_new:Nn \__mo_list_item:nn { \item[#1] #2 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\createlist{listone} % A description list specifically
\additem{listone}{item1}{description1}
\additem{listone}{item2}{description2}

\makelist{listone}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A more flexible implementation, where you can vary the formatting of the list.

The value for the `command` key can use `#1` and `#2` for referring to the two parts of the items.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\createlist}{m}
 {
  \seq_new:c { g_mo_list_#1_seq }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\additem}{mmm}
 {
  \seq_gput_right:cn { g_mo_list_#1_seq } { \__mo_list_do:nn {#2}{#3} }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\makelist}{O{}m}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { mo/list } { #1 }
  \l__mo_list_pre_tl
  \seq_use:cn { g_mo_list_#2_seq } { }
  \l__mo_list_post_tl
  \group_end:
 }
\keys_define:nn { mo/list }
 {
  pre     .tl_set:N  = \l__mo_list_pre_tl,
  post    .tl_set:N  = \l__mo_list_post_tl,
  command .code:n    = \cs_set:Nn \__mo_list_do:nn { #1 },
  pre     .initial:n = { \begin{description} },
  post    .initial:n = { \end{description} },
  command .initial:n = \item[#1] #2,
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\createlist{listone} % A description list specifically
\additem{listone}{item1}{description1}
\additem{listone}{item2}{description2}

\makelist{listone}

\bigskip

\makelist[
  pre=\begin{tabular}{ll} Item & Description \\ \hline,
  post=\end{tabular},
  command=#1 & #2 \\,
]{listone}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It works. With the search parameters KJO gave me I was able to find a question like mine that you also answered! If only I had known how to search for it. Now I will need to understand it. Thanks!

Comment: @M.O. I added a different implementation where it's easier to change the list making.